# Unable to install drivers of Nokia X on Windows 8.1

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-drivers, nokia-x

I have connected my Nokia X device with my PC which is running Windows 8.1. But in Device Manager it is showing as shown in below image:

[image]

When I Right click on it and select `Update Driver Software` and manually give the path of Android SDK where USB drivers are there, then it is showing below error (even though the driver files are available there):

[image]

Can anyone please help me what/where the problem can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK does not have specific drivers for all devices; really on Nexus devices and those devices that use Google's vendor ID are directly supported (on Windows at least).

The drivers can be modified to work with different devices though; I found a version for the Nokia X [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-x/general/fix-updated-adb-drivers-nokia-x-v1-2-4-1-t2835827).

You could also manually modify them yourself by following [this procedure](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/98825/1465) (using the correct IDs for your device instead).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes win8 will refuse using drivers as they aren't signed for win8. Same problem occured on my machine when trying to install the drivers for xperia z2.

You can try this:

Press and hold "shift" and reboot win8, then choose "startup options" or similar entry in the menu, then choose reboot. Choose option 7 or F7 and reboot again.

Driver should install now.